# Get pixels of a bitmap with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, bitmap, pixel

I am trying to write a greasemonkey javascript code for specifically my own page. In the page, there is an img with id "barcode".

I can use

```
var imageattributes = document.getElementById('barcode');
```

and get the image from the page.
What I want is that I want to be able to get all the pixels in this image in an array.

I have been going around in stackoverflow, and saw some ways to do this. I also saw pixastic. My problem with the solutions in stackoverflow is that

```
var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
```

does not work. No matter what I do.
And pixastic does not show how I can view the pixel information anywhere. Their documentation only covers the functions they already have for inversion, blur, etc.

The code I currently have is this:

```
var imageattributes = document.getElementById('barcode').attributes;
var imageurl = imageattributes.getNamedItem("src").value;
var imageurl2 = imageurl.replace("..","http://localhost");

var img = new Image();
img.src = imageurl2;
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var imgData = context.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.height, canvas.width);
var pixel = new Array();
for(i=0;i<canvas.height;i++){
    pixel[i] = new Array();
    for(j=0;j<canvas.width;j++){
        pixel[i][j] = imgData.data[i*canvas.width+j*4];
    }
}
document.getElementById('derp').innerHTML = imageurl;
```

Which is supposed to get the image, take it's src, load it as a new image, and put the pixels inside an array. And the last line is just to show on the screen if the code has worked or not, so if the url prints, it means it worked, if it doesn't, it doesn't.

Can anyone please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: In what way does `getImageData` not work?  Does it throw an error or return `null` or something else?

Comment: @apsillers I am unable to see the error or what is happening. I just deleted everything and wrote the code line by line, checking if the last line works and writes something on the webpage. When I came to that particular line, it stopped working.

Comment: Can you do a `console.log` and view the result in your console?  What is the result?  Is `imgData.data` populated?

Comment: I'm running the javascript codes on firefox line by line on the web console. It stops working on the line context.drawImage(img, 0, 0) because context is not defined. I saw somewhere that I should put var context = document.getElementById('barcode').getContext('2d') first but that does not work either. It says the getContext is not a function. So I guess that is where I go wrong?

Comment: Wait, do you not have a `<canvas>` element?  That's the central component of this entire function.  Writing an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have (or aren't using) a `<canvas>` element.  Your HTML should look something like this:

```
<img id="barcode" src="whatever.bmp">
<canvas id="mycanvas">
    <div id="fallback">
        You only see this message if your browser doesn't support canvas.
    </div>
<canvas>
```

And your function should be prefixed with:

```
var context = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
```

That should make your code function properly.  You need to get the drawing context of a `<canvas>` element first, then add the image to that context, and finally retrieve pixel data from the context.

To directly address your comment above, the line

```
var context = document.getElementById('barcode').getContext('2d');
```

tries to get the context of an image element, but that is not possible.  You can only call `getContext` on a canvas element.

Comment: This worked nicely :D Thank you! Although I had to edit the canvas.height and canvas.width to some other thing, but it still worked. Thank you.